# gpg --import on Heroku

Tags: heroku, gnupg

I am trying to run the following commands on Heroku to import and trust a PGP public key which I need to use to encrypt a file before sending it via SFTP:

```
heroku run gpg --import key.asc
heroku run gpg --edit-key email@example.com
```

The first command seems to work, but when I run the second command it fails to find the key. I get the following output when running `heroku run gpg --list-keys`:

```
gpg: directory '/app/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/app/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: /app/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
```

This may be due to the fact that Heroku does not allow writing to the file system, but I wanted to see if anyone knows what is going on and can help me figure out how to use this public key for encryption. It works locally using the iostreams gem to run something similar to the third example [here](https://github.com/rocketjob/iostreams#copying-between-files)

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is in the first command.The key.asc file in not in the dyno, it is on your computer. So, it is not importing anything.

You can run: `heroku run bash` and play directly inside the dyno.

Hope it helps!!!